# Light up image on hover

Tags: html, css, opacity

Take a look at http://www.kickstarter.com.

When you hover over their logo, the image lights up. Is this effect doable without using a different image on hover?

My first idea was to use `::after:hover` and add a white square with high transparency that covers the logo, **but since my logo is placed on a blue background this would not work.** Another idea is to set opacity to 0.9 and on hover set it to 1. But this makes the image look too dark by default.

Comment: this can be easily achieved by using css `opacity`

Comment: @Morpheus Please tell me how?

Comment: For images that aren't transparent png, you can have an invisible container containing your img. On hover of container, make the background white. On hover of img, make the opacity 0.9. Does the desired effect.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't do what you require with pure CSS at this point, due to the blue background. I think your best bet is edit the image in photoshop to be its `:hover` brightness, and then use something like:

```
img { 
  opacity: 0.7; 
} 

img:hover { 
  opacity: 1; 
}
```

<strike>Changing the opacity on hover will work:</strike>

```
img:hover {
   opacity: 0.5;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SnP6M/)

Comment: @Morpheus Yes if the background is white, but as I wrote in my question (that apparently no one read), my background is dark blue. So when I lower the opacity of the image it gets darker. Christ

Comment: @lawls You need to calm down a bit, people are trying to help and you are getting mad at them for that. You can't make an image brighter, of course you can't. Make the original image the brightness you want on `:hover`, and then lower the opacity to its current brightness for default. Also - a jsFiddle really helps us understand the current situation

Comment: @andy I know people are trying to help. But I get lots of downvotes because no one understood the question... Since it's doable with Photoshop to adjust the alpha and make an image brighter I was just wondering if it was doable with CSS too.

Comment: @lawls As far as I'm aware it isn't, not yet at least. Updated my answer

Comment: Can transition be more FLUENT?

Answer (score 36):

You may be able to use the css image filters, like this:

```
img:hover {-webkit-filter: brightness(150%); }
```

This sometimes looks funny and will only work in webkit browsers, but it's the best solution I could think of. It'll allow you to keep your blue background as well.

Here's a jsfiddle showing the Kickstarter logo on a blue background.

http://jsfiddle.net/62bCB/

Cheers,

Comment: While I needed a cross-browser solution this is certainly cool - and a step in the right direction. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Perfect for my case, exactly what I was looking for.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The original CSS has:

```
img:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: .8;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/hfUpk/

Comment: As i said in my question, my header is blue, so lowering the opacity makes the logo darker. http://jsfiddle.net/hfUpk/1/

Comment: Give a `background-color: #fff;` to the parent of the image. Simple.

Comment: But I dont want that? The logo is a transparent png placed on a wide header div with a blue background.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices depending on what browsers you need to support.  You could make the logo a background image and then change the image on hover. (or sprite the image so that you don't get a flicker)

Or you could try a combination of CSS opacity and microsoft filters for older versions of IE.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp

Since you mention you have a dark background you can try some of the new CSS filters (saturation, brightness etc) but you're out of luck for IE. 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/filters/understanding-css/

Answer (score 1):

You could use this CSS code which makes lighting up a smoother transition than just instantly bright.  Techpp.com and Techlivewire.com also use this same css or one similar to it on their frontpage featured sections.  I could not get CSS to post on here since stackoverflow kept giving me errors so I put it in a pastie. http://paste2.org/1L9H2XsF

Answer (score 1):

you can use opacity value between 0.1 to 1
 very light and 1 value is dark (default)

```
img {
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
img:hover {
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```