# Is it possible for me to use CSS to have an image light up with mouseover?

Tags: html, css, image

I am trying to use CSS and HTML to create an effect where someone can mouse-over a specific image on my page, and the image would appear to "light up", or at least do something cool. In the included snippet, I am trying to do this to the circular image in the innerArticle class. What would be an effective way to go about achieving this?

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header'
    'nav article ads'
    'nav footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #0ad05b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #e3eaee;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}
footer,
article,
nav,
div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #061621;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}
textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}
#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
}
#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#mainArticleShip {
  grid-area: article;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}
#siteAds {
  grid-area: ads;
}
/* Form Style */
#mainArticleForm {
  background: linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(6, 22, 33, 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 0)),
    url(https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
#mainArticle {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(6, 22, 33, 0.7), rgb(0, 0, 0)),
    url(https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
.innerArticleSignup {
  background: transparent;
}
.innerArticleForm {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent;
}
.text {
  background: transparent;
}
.reviewForm {
  background: transparent;
}
.innerArticleForm h1 {
  color: #e3eaee;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.innerArticleForm h2 {
  color: #e3eaee;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
form {
  padding: 39px;
}
.form__group {
  background: #000000a1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.form__group label {
  width: 232px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
.form__group select {
  padding: 6px;
  float: right;
}
.form__group input {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
}
.form__group textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #767676;
}

.primary {
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 22px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #0ad05b;
  border: 2px solid #989898;
}
.innerArticle {
  height: 17vh;
  width: 17vh;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.big-user-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.userAvatar {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.mainPage {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.headerRight {
  grid-area: header;
  justify-self: right;
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
}

.left {
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  align-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
}

.form-user-photo {
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1.6rem 15rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.alert--success {
  background-color: #0ad05b;
}
.alert--error {
  background-color: #eb4d4b;
}
.stars-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: transparent;
}

.stars-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '★★★★★';
  color: lightgray;
}

.stars-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '★★★★★';
  color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stars-0:after {
  width: 0%;
}
.stars-10:after {
  width: 10%;
}
.stars-20:after {
  width: 20%;
}
.stars-30:after {
  width: 30%;
}
.stars-40:after {
  width: 40%;
}
.stars-50:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.stars-60:after {
  width: 60%;
}
.stars-70:after {
  width: 70%;
}
.stars-80:after {
  width: 80%;
}
.stars-90:after {
  width: 90%;
}
.stars-100:after {
  width: 100;
}

.shipImage {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 175px;
  height: auto;
}

.otherShips {
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas:
      'header'
      'article'
      'ads'
      'nav'
      'footer';
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .form__group {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .innerArticleForm,
  .reviewForm,
  form {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .innerArticleForm {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 557px) {
  .innerArticleForm {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    
</head>

<body>
    <header id="pageHeader">
        <div class="left"><a href="/"><img class="logo"
                    src="https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/logo.png"></a></div>
        <div class="right">
            <p><a href="/signup">Sign up</a> | <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
        </div>
    </header>
    <article id="mainArticle">
        <div class="text">
            <h2>All Cruise Ships</h2>
            <p>Welcome to CruiseCrunch - the ultimate destination for cruise research. Enjoy free access to user reviews
                and ratings for cruise ships across the industry. If you have cruised before, please <a
                    href="/addreview">leave a review</a> of your trip for others. </p>
        </div>
        <div class="innerArticle"><a href="/ship/disney-dream"><img class="mainPage" src="https://www.goport.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ship-photo-shopped.jpg"
                    alt="Disney Dream"></a><br>Disney Dream<br><br><span
                class="stars-container stars-20">★★★★★</span><br><br><a href="/ship/disney-dream">See Reviews (1)</a>
        </div>
    </article>
    <nav id="mainNav">Navigation<div class="nav">
            <div class="ul">
                <div class="li"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-ship"></i> All Ships</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/addreview"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Review</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/topships"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Top Rated Ships</a></div>
                <div class="li"> <a href="/bestforkids"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Best For Kids</a></div>
                <div class="li"> <a href="/bestvalue"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Best Value</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/cabins"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Best Cabins</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/bestdining"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i> Best Dining</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/entertainment"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> Best Entertainment</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/worstships"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Lowest Rated Ships</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/recentreviews"><i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i> Most Recent Reviews</a></div>
                <div class="li"><a href="/newships"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> New Ships</a></div>
                <div class="li"><br></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="siteAds">Over 6 cruise ship reviews!</div>
    <footer id="pageFooter">
        <p class="footer">&#169; 2020, CruiseCrunch</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: simply use the :hover effect and use what ever you can or want. Liek glowing shadow, changing opacity... Literally everythign that can be done with CSS.

Comment: You may be interested by this previous post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275344/light-up-image-on-hover :)

Comment: Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter (in your case brightness and contrast may interest you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `filter` and reset `brightness`

```css
img.mainPage {
  filter: brightness(50%);
  transition:.1s cubic-bezier(.20,-4,.80,4)
;
}

img.mainPage:hover {
  filter: brightness(100%);
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header header' 'nav article ads' 'nav footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #0ad05b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #e3eaee;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}

footer,
article,
nav,
div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #061621;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}

textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}

#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
}

#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#mainArticleShip {
  grid-area: article;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

#siteAds {
  grid-area: ads;
}


/* Form Style */

#mainArticleForm {
  background: linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(6, 22, 33, 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url(https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

#mainArticle {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(6, 22, 33, 0.7), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url(https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}

.innerArticleSignup {
  background: transparent;
}

.innerArticleForm {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent;
}

.text {
  background: transparent;
}

.reviewForm {
  background: transparent;
}

.innerArticleForm h1 {
  color: #e3eaee;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.innerArticleForm h2 {
  color: #e3eaee;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

form {
  padding: 39px;
}

.form__group {
  background: #000000a1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form__group label {
  width: 232px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}

.form__group select {
  padding: 6px;
  float: right;
}

.form__group input {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
}

.form__group textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #767676;
}

.primary {
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 22px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #0ad05b;
  border: 2px solid #989898;
}

.innerArticle {
  height: 17vh;
  width: 17vh;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.big-user-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.userAvatar {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.mainPage {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.headerRight {
  grid-area: header;
  justify-self: right;
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
}

.left {
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  align-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
}

.form-user-photo {
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1.6rem 15rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.alert--success {
  background-color: #0ad05b;
}

.alert--error {
  background-color: #eb4d4b;
}

.stars-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: transparent;
}

.stars-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '★★★★★';
  color: lightgray;
}

.stars-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '★★★★★';
  color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stars-0:after {
  width: 0%;
}

.stars-10:after {
  width: 10%;
}

.stars-20:after {
  width: 20%;
}

.stars-30:after {
  width: 30%;
}

.stars-40:after {
  width: 40%;
}

.stars-50:after {
  width: 50%;
}

.stars-60:after {
  width: 60%;
}

.stars-70:after {
  width: 70%;
}

.stars-80:after {
  width: 80%;
}

.stars-90:after {
  width: 90%;
}

.stars-100:after {
  width: 100;
}

.shipImage {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 175px;
  height: auto;
}

.otherShips {
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */

@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas: 'header' 'article' 'ads' 'nav' 'footer';
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .form__group {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .innerArticleForm,
  .reviewForm,
  form {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .innerArticleForm {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 557px) {
  .innerArticleForm {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <header id="pageHeader">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="/"><img class="logo" src="https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p><a href="/signup">Sign up</a> | <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <article id="mainArticle">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>All Cruise Ships</h2>
      <p>Welcome to CruiseCrunch - the ultimate destination for cruise research. Enjoy free access to user reviews and ratings for cruise ships across the industry. If you have cruised before, please <a href="/addreview">leave a review</a> of your trip for
        others. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="innerArticle">
      <a href="/ship/disney-dream"><img class="mainPage" src="https://www.goport.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/ship-photo-shopped.jpg" alt="Disney Dream"></a><br>Disney Dream<br><br><span class="stars-container stars-20">★★★★★</span><br><br><a href="/ship/disney-dream">See Reviews (1)</a>
    </div>
  </article>
  <nav id="mainNav">Navigation
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="ul">
        <div class="li"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-ship"></i> All Ships</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/addreview"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Review</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/topships"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Top Rated Ships</a></div>
        <div class="li"> <a href="/bestforkids"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Best For Kids</a></div>
        <div class="li"> <a href="/bestvalue"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Best Value</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/cabins"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Best Cabins</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/bestdining"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i> Best Dining</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/entertainment"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> Best Entertainment</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/worstships"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Lowest Rated Ships</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/recentreviews"><i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i> Most Recent Reviews</a></div>
        <div class="li"><a href="/newships"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> New Ships</a></div>
        <div class="li"><br></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="siteAds">Over 6 cruise ship reviews!</div>
  <footer id="pageFooter">
    <p class="footer">&#169; 2020, CruiseCrunch</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter
>
> `brightness()`
>
> The `brightness()` function applies a linear multiplier to the input image, making it appear more or less bright. A value of `0%` will create an image that is **completely black**. A value of `100%` leaves the input **unchanged**. Other values are linear multipliers on the effect. Values of an amount `over 100%` are allowed, providing **brighter** results. The lacuna value for interpolation is 1.

Aside, you can use a transition and increase its effect with a bounce effect from a `cubic-bezier(x,x,x,x)` value for the `transition-timing-function` : https://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transitions-cubic-bezier-timing-function/

Answer (score 0):

You can apply :hover on every elemnt including images like in the snippet below. Then you can style every difference during hover effect you want. For everything you cant do in css you would need JS.

```css
img {
  width:50%;
  opacity: 80%;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px blue; 
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px blue; 
  box-shadow:0 0 20px blue;
  opacity: 100%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.tacoshy.de/Images/Yoshi/IMAG0735.jpg">
```

Comment: Vendor prefixes are pretty much unnecessary at this point for `box-shadow`.

Comment: `opacity` valid values stand in between 0 and 1.  You probably meant here 0.8 and 1. ;)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus 0.8 are 80%. opacity can either be writen as decimal number or percentages. The result is the same.